# list files in directories that contain a given name

Tags: bash, find, ls

How to list all java files whose absolute paths contain the word opt? this works:

```
$ find . -name *.java | grep "opt"
```

But I need the sizes of those files as well (similar to `ls`)? I've tried the following but failed:

```
$ ls -l *opt*/*.java
$ find *opt* -name *.java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -type f -path "*/opt/*.java" -printf "%f %s\n"
```

Search for a specific directory/file path using -path and then use printf to print the file name (%f) and the file size (%s)